# open virtual box from live cd error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, livecd

I am running linux mint in my laptop. I made some modifications and I couldn't login in linux enviroment. I boot in live cd (linux mint) and I recover my important files from desktop.

I had some important files in virtual machine. I install virtual box in live cd and when I double click in file.vbox it appears the message:

"Failed to open virtual machine located in /media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox. A differencing image of snapshot {xxxxxxxxxxxxxx} could not be found. Could not find an open hard disk with UUID {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}. "

I try also to "create new virtual machine" and then "use an existing virtual hard drive" and choose the snapshot but it pop up another message:

Failed to open the hard disk file /media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox.

Parent medium with UUID {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} of the medium '/media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox./Snapshots/{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}.vdi' is not found in the media registry ('/home/mint/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml').

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: Medium Interface: IMedium {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} Callee: IVirtualBox {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (xxxxxxxxxxx)

Can anyone help me to recover my files from virtual box?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

How I fixed it:

1. Backup your `yourVirtualMachine.vbox` file.
2. Open your `yourVirtualMachine.vbox` file with editor.
3. Search through the `.vbox` file for your missing UUID e.g. `36bbf5bd-3a5e-48ab-80d6-6a2952788fdc`.
4. You should find a section with attributes like this:

   ```
   <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="true" port="0" device="0">
     <Image uuid="{36bbf5bd-3a5e-48ab-80d6-6a2952788fdc}"/>
   </AttachedDevice>
   ```
5. Delete the whole section beginning by and end by (if you have a backup of your vbox file).
6. Save your edited file.
7. Start your VirtualBox, you should be able to import your virtual machine with these vbox file.
8. Edit your imported VM.
9. Open the tab "storage" in edit window.
10. Add a new hard disk (your existing VM file e.g. vdi, vmdk) to IDE- or SATA-Controller.

Hopefully, you should be able to start your VM.

I answered the same question on [open virtual box from live cd error at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721896).